# ArchiveFiles@2 and the root folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following code in my yaml pipeline which builds on an on-premises self hosted agent. This self hosted agent does not have winzip / 7zip installed

```
buildlabel: 11.0.46999
mycomponentInstallerRootDir: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\myproduct\installer\mycomponent\$(buildlabel)
mycomponent: 'test'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: $(mycomponentInstallerRootDir)
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(mycomponent)/$(buildlabel).zip'
    includeRootFolder: false
  enabled: true

- publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  artifact: buildartifacts_installer
  enabled: true
```

My requirement is to achieve the following:

- `test/11.0.46999.zip` must be generated as a build artifact
- `11.0.46999.zip` must have only the files and folders under `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\myproduct\installer\mycomponent\11.0.46999`

But what I am observing is that `test/11.0.46999.zip` has an intermediate folder `11.0.46999` which contains the files and folders under `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\myproduct\installer\mycomponent\11.0.46999`

I have tried with `includeRootFolder: false` as per the MSDN documentation, but still am unable to get rid of this intermediate folder in the generated zip file

[image: the generated zip file]

What am I missing here in my approach?

Thanks

**Edit 1:**
// Some more details in response to the note by @KrzysztofMadej

[image]

**Edit 2:**
I can add one more bit of information:

The build log shows the following command being executed as part of the Archive task

```
C:\AzAgent\_work\_tasks\ArchiveFiles_d8b84976-e99a-4b86-b885-4849694435b0\2.161.0\7zip\7z.exe a -tzip -mx=5 <mycomponentInstallerRootDir>\11.0.46999.zip @C:\AzAgent\_work\_temp\r5rzi127rs15lwec2nyk9ms4i
```

Comment: Can you add step `- script: ls $(mycomponentInstallerRootDir)` to be sure that you don't have `11.0.46999/11.0.46999` structure folder? It is a bit stupid but I checked what you have here and it works like expected.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej: I have updated my initial post with some more details along the lines of your suggestion

Comment: Cannot reproduce above scenario. `includeRootFolder: false` works fine for me. Is the variable `buildlabel: 11.0.46999` hard coded just like above in the real yaml file, or above is just an example. Can you echo  $(mycomponentInstallerRootDir) in your pipeline to check if the path is evaluated to `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\myproduct\installer\mycomponent\11.0.46999`

Answer (score 0):

That is because your root directory $(mycomponentInstallerRootDir);

mycomponentInstallerRootDir:

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\myproduct\installer\mycomponent\$(buildlabel)
```

Already contains the $(buildlabel) at the end of it, therefore in ArchiveFile task the ArchiveFile line should be;

```
archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(mycomponent).zip'
```